# How to judge the rank relationship of matrix equation $AB=E$

Tags: matrix-rank

**Note:** The following questions are from the 5th question of the [2010 Chinese Graduate Mathematical Entrance Examination](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/22edbe503086bceb19e8b8f67c1cfad6195fe9ff.html) (first set):

Suppose `A` is an $m*n$ matrix, `B` is an $n*m$ matrix, and $AB=E$ (`E` is the m-order unit matrix), then the following conclusions are correct (r(X) represents the rank of matrix X):

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&(A)&  r(A)=m, \quad   r(B)=m 
&(B)&   r(A)=m, \quad   r(B)=n \\
&(C)&   r(A)=n, \quad   r(B)=m 
&(D)&    r(A)=n, \quad  r(B)=n 
\end{array}$$

At present, I know that $r(E) = m$,$r(A) \le \max(m,n)$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? What can you say about $r(AB)$ given $r(A)$ and $r(B)$? What is $r(E)$?

Comment: Hint: Why is it true that $m\leq n$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr If $n < m$, then $r(A) \le n$, $r(B) \le n$, then $r (AB) \le \min \{r(A),r(B)\} \le n < m$, which is contradictory to $r(AB) = m$, so $n \ge m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, we have $r(A) \leq m$. And we have $m = r(E) = dim(im(E)) \leq dim(im(A)) = r(A)$. Then $r(A) = m$.

We have $B^T A^T = (AB)^T = E^T = E$. Then by the same reasoning, $r(B^T) = m$. Then $r(B) = m$.